# Catch HTML5 autoplay not available

Tags: html, video, html5-video

So there is this *** restriction: [HTML 5 Autoplay Google Chrome Android Not Playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19543634/html-5-autoplay-google-chrome-android-not-playing)

It is not possible to autoplay a video on Chrome Android.

How can I catch this in the code?

```
if (video.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture) {
  // Display a call to action for starting video
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a routine similar to what Modernizr does ... it dynamically creates a video element with a tiny inline base64 src, then tests autoplay on that to determine whether or not the functionality is supported. You can see the source here:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/video/autoplay.js

It'll still create some overhead (as even a small video encoded to base64 takes up significant space), but it's a workable solution.

Comment: I can't believe there is no official API to access this (forced) configuration! Anyways, thanks, I'll do the same check but using the actual video I'm trying to launch instead of overheading with a 1px one.